# job scheduler for script and rest call execution

Tags: java, node.js, scheduler

I am planning to build UI based scheduler custom for our business requirement. In GUI user can schedule a task like running script or calling rest on calendar. I have a clear idea what I need to build but before starting I need to find if there is already open source application which satisfy my requirement. Specifically I am looking for java based or nodejs based application so that we can use and contribute in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that nodejs is javascript which is completely different than java.
Here is a list of java scheduling scripts.
http://toppersworld.com/top-10-open-source-java-job-schedulers/